# Django, reverse lazy gives NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to update one field of my model, I have overridden the get_success_url method in the updateview, but it is not working.

```
class MensajeApropiado(UpdateView):
    model = Mensaje
    form_class = FormMensaje
    template_name = 'foro/msjCensura.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('mensajes', args=(self.object.tema.id,))
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required as LR
url(r'^mensajes/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ListaMensajes.as_view(),  name="mensajes"),
url(r'^msjcensura/(?P<pk>\d+)/', LR(MensajeApropiado.as_view()), name="censura"),
```

This is the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}


{% block content %}



Fecha en Perú: {% now "m-d-Y" %}

<div>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Foros</a> > <a
        href="{% url 'temas' mensaje.tema.foro.id %}">{{ mensaje.tema.foro.titulo }}</a>
    > <a href="{% url 'mensajes' mensaje.tema.id %}">{{ mensaje.tema.titulo }}</a> > Censura del mensaje
</div>


{% if mensaje.tema.autor.user.id == request.user.id and request.user.is_authenticated %}
    Tema: {{ mensaje.tema.titulo }} - {{ mensaje.tema.fecha|date:"M-d-Y" }}
    - Autor: <a href="{% url 'editar_perfil' request.user.id %}">{{ mensaje.tema.autor }} </a>
{% else %}
    Tema: {{ mensaje.tema.titulo }} - {{ mensaje.tema.fecha|date:"M-d-Y" }}
    - Autor: <a href="{% url 'detalle_usuario' mensaje.autor.id %}">{{ mensaje.autor }} </a>
{% endif %}
<br><br>

<div id="no-more-tables">

    <table style='table-layout:fixed;width:100%' class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">

        <thead class="cf">
        {% with mensaje.profile_data as pdata %}
            <tr>

                <th style='width: 15%;'>
                    Autor

                </th>
                <th class="celdacontenido" style='width: 85%;'>
                    {{ mensaje.fecha|date:"M, d-Y, h:i a" }}

                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td data-title='Autor'>
            {% if mensaje.autor.id == request.user.id and request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'editar_perfil' request.user.id %}"> {{ mensaje.autor }} </a><br>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'detalle_usuario' mensaje.autor.id %}"> {{ mensaje.autor }} </a><br>
            {% endif %}

            {% if request.user.is_staff %} Administrador<br>
            {% else %}
                Miembro<br>
            {% endif %}

            {% if  pdata.1 %}
                <img border="0" alt="Profile Pic" src="/media/{{ pdata.1 }}"/><br>
            {% else %}
                <img border="0" alt="Profile Pic" src="/media/imagenes/nouserimg.png" height="140" width="140"/><br>
            {% endif %}

            Fecha de registro: <br> {{ mensaje.autor.date_joined|date:"M-d-Y" }} <br>
            Número de mensajes: {{ pdata.0 }}
        {% endwith %}
        </td>
        <td align="justify" class="celdacontenido" data-title='{{ mensaje.fecha|date:"m-d-Y, h:i a" }}'>
            {{ mensaje.contenido }}<br>
        </td>

        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
<b>Desmarcando la casilla el mensaje se catalogará como inapropiado, caso contrario al seleccionar
    la casilla, será apropiado.</b> <br><br>

<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Apropiado:
    {{ form.apropiado }}<br><br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Confirmar" id="submit"/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

When I click on

```
<a href="{% url 'censura' mensaje.id %}" class="apropiado">Marcar como inapropiado</a>
```

from my other template, it works, I can see the 'censura' template without problems, but when I click on the submit button it gives the NoReverseMatch at /msjcensura/5/

```
Reverse for 'detalle_usuario' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['usuario/(?P<pk>\\d+)/']
```

at

```
{% url 'detalle_usuario' mensaje.autor.id %}
```

I don't understand this, I have specified other view ('mensajes'), but it goes to the same template (censura).

**Edit**, I had the url, I forgot to type it in the question, because the problem was in the redirect and the mensaje.autor.id returning 'None':

```
 url(r'^usuario/(?P<pk>\d+)/', LR(DetalleUsuario.as_view()), name="detalle_usuario"),
```

And the view:

```
class DetalleUsuario(DetailView):
model = PerfilUsuario
template_name = "foro/detalleUsuario.html"
```

Comment: Either `mensaje.autor` or `mensaje.autor.id` is None. If you print out `mensaje.autor` what do you get?

Comment: I have changed the code, I am using  two views : MensajeCensura(request, **kwargs) to render the template and ConfirmarCensura(request) to update the field and now it works, I know this is not the solution for the question,but I need this project working for tuesday

Comment: You don't have `detalle_usuario` url

Comment: Hello,I have added that info

Answer (score 1):

reverse() is used in function based views while reverse lazy() is used in class based views.

Example:

Calling the django reverse functionality from the get_success_url () method.

```
class MensajeApropiado(UpdateView):
    model = Mensaje
    form_class = FormMensaje
    template_name = 'foro/msjCensura.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('mensajes', args=(self.object.tema.id,))
```

Calling from success_url parameter.

```
class MensajeApropiado(UpdateView):
    model = Mensaje
    form_class = FormMensaje
    template_name = 'foro/msjCensura.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mensajes', args=(self.object.tema.id,))
```

This is because class attributes are evaluated on import, reverse_lazy() handles the process of loading on import from within a class based view and reverse () from within a method of a class based view or a function based view. The answer to when or exactly how that happens, resides within the depths of python's import system.

See this answer also:  [Difference between reverse() and reverse_lazy() in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669514/difference-between-reverse-and-reverse-lazy-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Try

`{% url 'detalle_usuario' pk=mensaje.autor.id %}`

This will help target the correct url since the parameter in your url config is named. Also, it seems like, `mensaje.autor.id` is `None`. Can you try and debug that `mensaje.autor` is present, and has an `id`?