# Difference between reverse() and reverse_lazy() in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, url-routing

I understand that we can use `reverse()` in FBV and `reverse_lazy()` in CBV. I understand that we have to use `reverse_lazy()` in CBV as the urls are not loaded when the file is imported (Ref: [Reverse_lazy and URL Loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649804/reverse-lazy-and-url-loading))

What I don't understand is:

How are the urls loaded when we call `reverse` from the FBV? As when we import the views at the top of the `urls.py` in a Django app, `urlpatterns` list is yet to be evaluated. How does `reverse()` for FBV work but not for CBV?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
#importme.py
def a():
    print("FUNCTION HELLO")

class B():
    print("CLASS HELLO") 
    

>>> import importme
>>> CLASS HELLO
```

**Edit:**
The reason: The class creation process involves executing the body of the class.

> The class body is executed (approximately) as `exec(body, globals(), namespace)`. [...] Once the class namespace has been populated by
> executing the class body, the class object is created by calling
> `metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)`.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=metaclass#executing-the-class-body

---

---

*My original answer text. You can ignore it - I'm just leaving it in because mirek's comment was a direct response to it:*

Class attributes are evaluated on import. The answer to when or exactly how that happens, resides within the depths of python's import system.

Comment: >> resides within the depths of python's import system -- I think it resides in the principle of class not in the "depth of..". The defined class must have its attributes.

Answer (score 65):

Consider these two ways of defining the success_url.  The first is commented out,
the second is the function:

```py
class NewJobCBV(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'company/job.html'
    form_class = newJobForm
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('newJob')

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse("newJob")
```

@CoffeeBasedLifeform : you are right, class attributes are evaluated on import, I checked after reading your answer. So,

1. If we are using `success_url` we have to use `reverse_lazy()`.
2. If we are reversing inside a function we can use `reverse()`.

Now it is crystal clear.

Thanks CoffeeBasedLifeform :)

Comment: Is there any reason to use `reverse` then? Just use `reverse_lazy` all the time and don't worry if the urls are loaded. Does `reverse` have any benefits?

Answer (score 16):

**Reverse_lazy** is, as the name implies, a *lazy implementation* of the **reverse** URL resolver. Unlike the traditional reverse function, reverse_lazy won't execute until the value is needed.

It is useful because it prevent **Reverse Not Found** exceptions when working with URLs that may not be immediately known.

**Why do we need it?**
It's needed because, Class attributes are evaluated on import and at that time Reverse method will return 'Reverse Not Found'.
Later upon need, at the time of its execution, all the necessary code snippets will be executed already, to give a valid URL.

Answer (score 5):

Just understand the difference:

**reverse()** returns a `string` & **reverse_lazy()** returns an `<object>`

Comment: How does this explain the weird behavior? Genuinely asking.

Comment: explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75653186/6710903

Answer (score 5):

**difference:**

1. reverse() use in function & reverse_lazy() use in class.
2. reverse() returns a string & reverse_lazy() returns an object.

Answer (score 2):

Both `reverse` and `reverse_lazy` functions have the same objective: to generate a URL based on the inputs (like a named url).

### The difference is in when they are evaluated:

- `reverse` is used to generate a URL at the time the function or method is called.

Let's put an example:

*A function*:

```
#views.py

from django.urls import reverse

def my_view(request):
    url = reverse('url-name', args=[1])
    # do something with the URL
```

The `reverse` function is evaluated at the moment the `my_view` function is called: it generates a URL for the named url `url-name`, passing the integer 1 as an argument.

*A method*:

```
#models.py 

from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    #rest of the class

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Again, the `reverse` function is evaluated at the moment the `get_absolute_url` method is called.

What is important in both this cases is that at the moment the `reverse` function is called, **it already has the information of the `URLConf`**, so it can easily find the url pattern.

- `reverse_lazy` is also used to generate a URL, but it defers the moment of evaluation until it is actually needed. That's way it is a lazily evaluated version of `reverse`.

You may be wondering why...

There are moments in your code when you need to use a URL reversal, but you don't exactly know if the `URLConf` has already been loaded.
If you use `reverse` when the `URLConf` hasn't already been loaded, you would get an error.

This error occurs because reverse needs to know the URL patterns defined in the project's `URLConf` in order to generate the correct URL. If the `URLConf` has not been loaded, `reverse` will not be able to find the necessary information to generate the URL and will raise an exception.

Example:

*A class based view*:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
   model = Post
   template_name = "post_delete.html"
   success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

When you defined the `success_url` (*a class attribute*) you used `reverse_lazy` instead of `reverse`.
**This is because class attributes are evaluated at the time when the class definition is executed**. This means that the values assigned to class attributes are determined when the class is defined, and not when instances of the class are created.

When you import the class, the Python interpreter executes the class definition from top to bottom and that includes the *class atrtributes* like `success_url`, but there are chances that the `URLConf` hadn't been loaded.

To not have an error, instead of using `reverse` we use `reverse_lazy`, which delays the actual call to the `URLConf` to the moment is needed and not when the class attribute is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Because: Python class attributes are evaluated on the declaration.
Please read this link: [Python class attributes are...](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/20/python-class-attributes-are-evaluated-on-declaration.html)