# Database data is not updating on my apache2 website unless I restart apache2 service *EDIT

Tags: python, django, sqlite, apache2

I have Django installed and am using Apache2 to host the website (using WSGI). I have checkboxes on my website and when I click a checkbox and then click submit it saves the change to the SQLite3 database and refreshes my website. If I log out of my website and then back in the checkbox is no longer clicked but the related database item is showing TRUE in the Django admin site. If I restart Apache2 using "sudo service apache2 restart" and refresh the website it then has the proper boxes checked. I am brand new to Django/Apache2 so I apologize if this is a stupid mistake, but restarting apache2 every time I make a change seems wrong.

*EDIT- I have changed my code to use a modelform (I think I did it properly)as recommended by the first commenter, but I am having the same problem.

**my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import RelayList
from .forms import RelayControl
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


# Create your views here.
@login_required
def index(response):
    curList = RelayList.objects.get(id=1) #retrieves the database object and places it into a variable

    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RelayControl(response.POST, instance=curList)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = RelayControl() # creates an instance of the for defined in class RelayControl in forms.py

    #return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello World, from index in views.py</h1>')
    #"pageHeader" is the variable it looks for in the html file and places whatever is after the ":" in its spot
    return render(response, "power_relay/home.html", {"pageHeader":"Power Relay Controls", "controlForm":form, "curList":curList})



#@login_required
#def modify_model(response):



@login_required
def settings(response):
    return render(response, "power_relay/settings.html", {"pageHeader":"Power Relay Settings"})
```

**my main site HTML**

```
{% extends 'power_relay/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
        Power Relay Site- Controls
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
        <form method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{controlForm.as_p}}
                <button type="submit", name="saveChanges">Save Changes</button>
        </form>

        <hr><br><br>

        <a href="{% url 'settings'%}">Settings</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**my models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class RelayList(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        relay1 = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Relay 1")
        relay2 = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Relay 2")
        relay3 = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Relay 3")

        #relaylist = models.ForeignKey(RelayList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        #relayName = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        #onOff = models.BooleanField()

        def __str__(self):
                return self.name
```

**my forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import RelayList


class RelayControl(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RelayList
        fields = ['relay1', 'relay2', 'relay3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit:

```
class RelayControl(forms.Form):
        curList = RelayList.objects.get(id=1) #retrieves the relay list from database
```

Since you declare this in the form class body, the initial values for your form are set when your forms.py is imported ([here's a short explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669514/difference-between-reverse-and-reverse-lazy-in-django/48671384#48671384))- i.e. when the wsgi application starts. The values will remain fixed until the application re-imports forms.py.

---

A better, more reusable approach, is to use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/). In the view, you then pass the model instance (here: `curList = RelayList.objects.get(id=1)`) to it and django figures out the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and advice. It will take me some time to implement. I am somewhat new to Stack Overflow. Should I mark this as answered or wait until I implement the change and verify it works properly?

Comment: See if this fixes your problem first, then you can mark it as answered.

Comment: I think I implemented it properly but I am having the same issue.

Comment: The form for the response to the GET request also needs the model instance: `else: form = RelayControl(instance=curList)`. Now, if you want to be able to edit more than just the one Relay (`id=1`), you need to create separate views for creating and editing, and set up the url config accordingly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views

Comment: I should've caught that, thanks. Everything now works perfectly. Much appreciated.